# Why no (full) Hallel on the second day of Pesach?

Tags: passover, sefirat-ha-omer, musaf, hallel

On the last 6 days of Pesach, according to the Gemara, we don't say (full) Hallel because [the korban is the same for all 7 days](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/64271/11532).

[The second day of Pesach](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.23.12) has a unique korban.  So why don't we say Hallel on that day (and the third outside Israel)?  Do only the korbanos mentioned in Pinchas count for this purpose?

Comment: We don't mention it in the Musaf prayer probably for the same reason https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/104707/759

Comment: Most of the reasons in the answer there don't apply to the Omer, except for R' Ariel's