# Chag Ha'Bikurim

Tags: shavuos

Shavuoth, in addition to being Zman Matan Toratenu, is also Chag Ha'Bikurim.  Yet we do not refer to bikurim in the tfillot nor do read the Torah portions (or a haftorah) dealing with bikurim.

I have been unable to find any source that discusses this issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: We read וביום הבכורים in the maftir (and recite that in musaf)

Comment: Some have the custom to study the mishnayot of masechet bikkurim during the Shavuot meals.

Comment: Double AA is correct, but my question was not precise:  While we do read the section of kurbanot (sacrifices) which refers to Shavuoth as Yom Habikurim, we do not read the sections that refer to the ceremony of bringing the bikurim (see Devarim Perek 26 or in the mishnayot which Joel K refers to).  My question was why do we seemingly ignore this mitzvah?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/104707/759

Comment: Worth noting that Shavuot was only the start of the Bikkurim season, but that Bikkurim could be brought after Shavuot, until Sukkot (or even Chanukah). So this mitzvah is less associated to the specific day of Shavuot.

Answer (score 3):

Rashi (Bamidbar 28:26) says that the reason why Shavuos is called Yom Habikurim is because of the meal offering - the Shtei Halechem - which was the first to come from the new wheat of that year, which is called “Bikurei Ketzir Chitim” (Shemos 34:22), and is referred to in the Haftarah and Musaf as “Minchah Chadashah”

The Bikurim on the other hand, are not necessarily (and according to some should not be - see Minchas Chinuch Parshas Bo, Mitzvah 18:3) brought on Shavuos, and can be brought until Chanukah (Rambam Hilchos Bikurim 2:6), and the reason why they cannot be brought before Shavuos, is in order that the Shtei Halechem should be the first offering (aside from the Omer offering) to be brought from the new produce of that year (Menachos 84b)